# Use condition in my views

Tags: views, theming

I have a content type "event".I show all my events rejected or validated. Now in my view I want to show fontawesome icon like "cancel" to signal that the event is rejected and another fontawesome icon like "okey" to signal that the event is validate. How to use Global text to make it? I don't like to use page.tpl.php. But if there are a solution base it I can accept it.

Comment: How do you "reject" or "validate" your Events? Where exactly do you want to put the icon? I would use the Flag module for this and add the appropriate HTML in a `node--event.tpl.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a boolean field which stores if event is rejected or validated, you can read this information from PHP and print the fontawesome icon based on a condition.

The standard way in **Drupal 7** would be to use [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module and do something like:

```
if ($data->field_field_event_validated['0']['raw']['value'])
  echo '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';
else
  echo '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i>';
```

This module still isn't ported to **Drupal 8**, and actually it's really bad in terms of security and stability to use this module as [this article](http://enzolutions.com/articles/2015/10/11/how-to-include-php-code-in-drupal-8-views/) states. The same article describes how to include PHP in your views. In resume you have to create a module, generate a custom views field with the PHP code printing your icon and use this module in Views.